# Can an NSEvent be triggered when modifier key is pressed?

Tags: objective-c, nsevent

I'm looking to detect the exact moment that a modifier key (such as ctrl, shift, cmd, alt) is pressed.

The following code just triggers when non-modifier keys are pressed (where any modifier keys currently held down are reported per key event)

```
[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:(NSKeyDownMask) handler:^(NSEvent *event){//Trigger function}}];
```

Is there a way to expand this function to trigger exactly when modifier keys are keydown-ed and keyup-ed?

Comment: Have you tried `NSFlagsChangedMask` instead of `NSKeyDownMask`? Or the two masks combined, as `NSKeyDownMask | NSFlagsChangedMask`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I hadn't seen that before. I guess it is fair for this to be marked as a duplicate as Josh has done, but what I really want to have is a separate version of `NSKeyDownMask` and `NSKeyUpMask` for the modifier keys too. `NSFlagsChangedMask` fires on keyup and keydown of modifier keys.

Comment: I guess the only way is to compare events, as is mentioned in the linked original of this duplicate question

Comment: Yes, if the flag is on when you get the "changed" notice, then it's key down; if off, key up. Without getting into the Deep Magic of IO Kit, I'm fairly postive this is the best you can do. This `NSEvent` stuff is a wrapper around the next-lower API, `CGEventTap`s, but I don't recall them having much more functionality.